# TypeScript Type Inheritance : How to assign variable with parent type to the variable with child type

Tags: typescript

I have created two types

```
export class GenericType {
  public id: string;
  public property: string;
  public name: string;
}
export class SpecificType extends GenericType {
  public value: string;
}
```

Now I have two variable `A: GenericType` and `B: SpecificType`, now I want to assign all the values of `A` to `B`, and additionally, I want to assign `value` to `B`. How should I achieve this, I don't want to loop through `A`'s all property and manually assign it to `B`'s all property.

```
let varA: GenericType = {
  id: '123',
  property: 'exmple',
  name: 'example variable',
};

let varB: SpecificType = new SpecificType();
varB = varA;  <----- not allowing to assign.
varB.value = 'new value';
```

Comment: Do you really want `class` and not `interface` here?  Note that, even if you suppress or fix the error, `varB instanceof SpecificType` will return `false` if you do `varB = varA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** do this:

```
let varA: GenericType = {
  id: '123',
  property: 'exmple',
  name: 'example variable',
};

let varB: SpecificType = new SpecificType();
varB = varA;  <----- not allowing to assign.
varB.value = 'new value';
```

But you can do this:

```
let varA: GenericType = {
  id: '123',
  property: 'exmple',
  name: 'example variable',
};

let varB: SpecificType = new SpecificType();
// Difference here:
varB = { ...varA, value: 'new value' }
```

You cannot assign `varA` to `varB` because `varA` does not have `value`, but you can assign everything altogether using the `spread` operator.

Comment: Or you could use `Object.assign(new SpecificType(), varA, {value: 'new value'})` if you want to maintain the object identity and prototype chain

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to assign it because the property `value` does not exist in the `GenericType` class, to circumvent this you can do a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to `SpecificType`:

```
let varB: SpecificType = new SpecificType();
varB = varA as SpecificType; // Allowed to assign now.
varB.value = 'new value';
```

Comment: I would personally not recommend this because it allows you to forget to set properties that exist in SpecificType but do not exist in GenericType